# Invoke a method when system clock hit 12pm

Tags: java, servlets

I want to invoke a method from servlet when system clock reach to 12pm and that method basically send some data from database to user via Email.Please can anybody help me how i can achieve this in Java Servlet.

Comment: Do you want this to happen daily at 12 PM? if yes, then you can use task scheduler in windows or crontab in *inx boxes

Comment: Yes @PradeepSimha i want this to happen daily at 12 pm.

Comment: @RizN81, then you can use Quartz or in-built OS scheduler.

Comment: @PradeepSimha thank man but can i use it in Servlet?

Comment: @RizN81, yes you can. Search Quartz tutorials, you will get lot of details

Comment: Yes you can invoke quartz schedular as back-end process. Your current thread will start the process and will proceed to further servlet task  as usual. Remeber: Once JVM will shut down you have to invoke quartz again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) is the wrong tool for the job. It's intented to act on HTTP requests, nothing more. You want just a background task which runs once on daily basis. You can't expect from an enduser that s/he should fire a HTTP request at exactly that moment in order to trigger a "background job".

Apart from the legacy Quartz library as mentioned by many others (apparently hanging in legacy J2EE era), you can also just use the standard Java SE API provided [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) for that. This needs to be initiated by a simple [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) like this:

```
@WebListener
public class Scheduler implements ServletContextListener {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        long millisUntil12PM = calculateItSomehow();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new SendEmail(), millisUntil12PM, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }

}
```

Where the class `SendEmail` look like this:

```
public class SendEmail implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do your job here.
    }

}
```

That's all. No need to mess with a legacy 3rd party library.

Answer (score 5):

For scheduling a Job at specific time Quartz provided best API. You can create A job according to your need and create a trigger to invoke the job at 12 PM. just take a help of below link.
[Quartz Scheduler Example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/quartz-2-scheduler-example.html)